# Javascript 'cannot read property of undefined' in React Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, antd

**Simplified** I am new to react, and when I was rendering a dataset, I got errors "cannot read property map/0 of undefined" (two separate ones, **commented in code**). What really troubled me is that, when the dataSource (in this.state) is declared as a `const` outside the class component, everything functioned well but it didn't work as a state attribute of the App class.

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  var n = -1, m = 0;
  if (a === "important") {n = 2;} else if (a === "normal") {n = 1;} else {n = 0;}
  if (b === "important") {m = 2;} else if (b === "normal") {m = 1;} else {m = 0;}
  return n - m;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dataSource: [
      {key: "1", title: "Call Uber eats w/o my parents", levels: ["important"]},
    ],
    count: 2,
  };

  handleAdd = () => {
    const { count, dataSource } = this.state;
    const newData = {
      key: count, name: `Edward King ${count}`, age: 32, address: `London, Park Lane no. ${count}`
    };
    this.setState({dataSource: [...dataSource, newData], count: count + 1});
  };

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "Level", dataIndex: "levels", key: "levels",
        sorter: (a, b) => compare(a.levels[0], b.levels[0]),            // cannot read property '0' of undefined
        render: levels => (
          <>
            {levels.map(level => {
              let color = "";                                           // cannot read property 'map' of undefined
              if (level === "important") {color = "red";}
              else if (level === "normal") {color = "blue";}
              return (
                <Tag color={color} key={level}>{level.toUpperCase()}</Tag>
              );
            })}
          </>
        )
      },
    ];
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.handleAdd} type="primary">Add a row</Button>    // Original call
    );
  }
}
```

All I know is that somehow I must retrieve the data from the state of this class to prevent undefined properties, but I was confused when I passed parameters (not actual objects) to the functions and it still raised the errors described above.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This is the complete code for the return function. This wasn't included at the first iteration and is now included (thanks for editing).

```js
<Row justify="center" align="top">
  <Col style={{ maxWidth: 1080 }}>
    <Space style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
      <Button onClick={this.handleAdd} type="primary">
        Add a row
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={this.clearFilters}>Clear filters</Button>
      <Button onClick={this.clearAll}>Clear filters and sorters</Button>
    </Space>
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.dataSource}/>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: Your code is not that readable, or at least from a react perspective. I would suggest looking into this https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: also try doing `dataSource.levels.map` perhaps ...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem complete. For instance, `columns` is declared but is never used. How does it get used? All `App` is rendering is a `Button`, so those lines you have comments on are not getting executed. When does `sorter()` get called? When does that `render: levels => ...` get called and what do you pass to it for levels?

Comment: @EvanMorrison my apologies for not clarifying this. `sorter()` and `render` will automatically be called when the table is rendered in the main `return()` function, and I will attach the table-rendering code now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are directly accessing the levels property which is a part of object in dataSource array in state. That is why it is giving error of undefined on `levels`.

In render, get the state first --
`const levelsArr = this.state.dataSource[0].levels;`

Then try something like this code `compare(a.levelsArr[0], b.levelsArr[0])`

Also `{levelsArr && levelsArr.map(level => {`

Comment: Are there any ways that I can render it dynamically, like getting rid of the `dataSource[0]` and replacing this with something else? The datasource was only stripped down to one item because I'm trying to keep only the necessary things.